# TypeError, 'Class object' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to add an "event" in the admin and get this error:

> TypeError at /admin/sms/event/add/
>   'Contact' object is not subscriptable

```
models.py:

 class Contact(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="contact")
    name = models.CharField(_("Recipient"), max_length=40)
    phone = models.IntegerField(_("Phone"), max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s: %d" % (self.name, self.phone)

class Event(models.Model):
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, verbose_name=_("Calendar"), related_name="event_calendar")
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, verbose_name=_("Message"), related_name="event_message")
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Contact, verbose_name=_("Recipient"), related_name="event1")
    event_date = models.DateField(_("Date"))
    start_time = models.TimeField(_("Start time"))
    end_time = models.TimeField(_("End time"), blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(_("Location of meeting"), blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    reminder_options = models.IntegerField(choices=ReminderOptions.CHOICES, verbose_name=_("Reminder time"))
    content = models.CharField(_("Event Notes"), max_length=160)
    # recurring_options = models.IntegerField(choices=RecurringOptions.CHOICES, verbose_name=_("Recurring time"))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.recipient

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return u'/create-event/'
```

Comment: does it add it to the database and then throw the error ?

Comment: Do you have a customized admin model? If so please post our admin.py

Answer (score 0):

First guess is that your phone field gets a string from your admin form. Use a charField for phone in your model and make a custom form in your admin.py.

In models.py change your phone Integerfield to a CharField:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ...
    phone = models.CharField(_("Phone"), max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s: %s" % (self.name, self.phone) # %d becomes %s
```

In Admin.py create a form:

```
from models import Contact
from django import forms
from django_localflavor_fr.forms import FRPhoneNumberField

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = FRPhoneNumberField()
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/localflavor/

In Admin.py create a ModelAdmin:

```
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ContactForm
```